# How can i slow down my spritesheet animation in javascript?

Tags: javascript, animation, sprite-sheet, arrow-keys

I have made a simple spritesheet animation, but it is way too fast. It is also flashing for some reason.
My code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="raf.js"></script>
        <script>
            var ctx;
            var count = 0;
            var x;
            var y;
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = "images/character.png";
            img.onload = draw;

            function draw() {
                requestAnimationFrame(draw)

                ctx.clearRect(0,0,450,586);

                x = (count % 16) * 450;
                y = Math.floor(count / 16) * 586;
                ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, 450, 586, 0, 0, 450, 586);

                if(count == 16){
                    count = 0;
                } else {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            function init() {
                ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload = "init()">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600">
        </canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` runs (or attempts to run) callback at monitor refresh speed. Standard solution of controlling animation speed is to bind value changes to time, not screen updates.

Comment: @VallyN But how do i do that? I have tried things like setInterval and setTimeout, but so far i haven't got them working.

Comment: No-no-no. Just make count increasing not as fast as it is now. Replace `count++` with `count+=.1` and see for yourself.

Comment: @VallyN I replaced count++ with count+=.1 but now my spritesheet is just scrolling from the right to the left for some time and then just disappears. Weird.It is also flashing all the time now.

Comment: Line `x = (count % 16) * 450`: Multiply 16 by 450 and compare with width.

Comment: Also, in line `if(count == 16)` `count` may be never equal to 16. Read about floating point numbers and replace equality operator with greater-than-or-equal (`>=`) operator. Additionally you may want to use `fillRect` instead of `clearRect` and correct its position to erase/redraw area where sprite was - this may reduce flashing.

Comment: @VallyN I mean that the whole spritesheet is just scrolling from the right side of my canvas to the left side of my canvas now. It doesn't disappear anymore though. I checked the image width and it should be correct.

Comment: Sorry, I understood you incorrectly. Wait a sec, i post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to throttle your animation frame rate.

```
        var ctx;
        var count = 0;
        var x;
        var y;
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = "images/character.png";
        img.onload = draw;

        var time = Date.now();
        var delay = 100;

        function draw() {
            requestAnimationFrame(draw)

            ctx.clearRect(0,0,450,586);

            x = (count % 16) * 450;
            y = Math.floor(count / 16) * 586;
            ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, 450, 586, 0, 0, 450, 586);

            if(Date.now() - time >= delay){
                if(count == 16){
                    count = 0;
                } else {
                    count++;
                }
                if ((Date.now() - time - delay) > delay){
                    time = Date.now();
                } else {
                    time += delay;
                }
            }
        }

        function init() {
            ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        }
```

`delay` is frame delay in milliseconds (100 in example, means ~10 fps), `time` used to keep track of time current frame displayed.

Flashing problem might be related to missing sprite in sprite sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the above with SpriteAnimJS, it can be configured to use WebGL and canvas as fallback.

To run a spritesheet with it, as per its demo:

```
var mySpriteAnimation = new SpriteAnim(canvasIdHere,useOnlyCanvasBoolean)
mySpriteAnimation.start({
            frameWidth: 100,
            frameHeight: 100,
            image: image_element, // must be preloaded
            fps: 10,
            className: 'class_name',
            loop: true,
            onStart: function() {},
            onComplete: function() {}
        });
```

As you can see in the settings, you can set the FPS easily, without calculating them yourself.

Library + demos [here](http://catalinberta.github.io/spriteanimjs/)